# iostat: See current usage rather than average

Tags: linux, monitoring, device, iostat

I need to log disk statistics (MB/read, MB/write) of block devices. As I understand, `iostat` shows an average value. This is not exactly what I want when I'm about to monitor a server. Is there a way to show current values rather than the average?

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try

```
iostat 1
```

or for more detailed view

```
iostat -x 1
```

You should also check out command `sar`. Actually, in your case `sar` is probably what you want since you need the actual readings instead of averages. For example, `sar -d 1 1` shows you I/O statistics.

Comment: `iostat 1` prints the statistics every 1 second. This is not suitable for monitoring. `iostat 1 1` limits it to one output, but it seems the values are average again. I got exactly the same stats as yesterday.

Comment: OK then, I edited my reply a bit.

Answer (score 6):

Use the `-y` option to suppress the first print being averages:

```
iostat -y 1 1
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer as the `-y` actually accomplishes what the OP was asking for.

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. We can use this command line for benchmark scripts.